# How to increase font size relatively when font is pixel based?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to increase the font size of an element by a certain amount when the element css has a font size defined with pixel value?

For example, let's say someone else creates an element with a font size of 10px. I want to increase the font size by 25%.

So if I have an element can I add a class that will increase the font size by 125%? Example:

```js
function increase() {
   //log("test");
   //var container = getElementById("container");
   container.classList.add("adjuster");
}

function decrease() {
  //var container = getElementById("container");
  container.classList.remove("adjuster");
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.adjuster {
  font-size: 125%; // increase by 25%
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="main">
   Lorem Ipsum
</div>

<button onclick="increase()">
Increase
</button>

<button onclick="decrease()">
Decrease
</button>
```

Although it looks like it, it's not working. It's that 125% is larger than font-size: 15px.

Basically, is it possible to make a site with increase and decrease font size? BUT where it's not the body container and the font size is pixel based already.

Comment: It looks like it's working to me. What's the problem?

Comment: It's not working. It's that 125% is larger than font-size: 15px.

Comment: You are correct that it is not showing 125% of 15px. It is showing 125% of 16px (at least on my browser). I'll put a demo in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a pre defined class with increased fontsize, use window.getComputedStyle to get the current font size, alculate 25% of current value and increase it by that number.

```
function increase() {
   var container = document.getElementById("container");
   var style= window.getComputedStyle(container , null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
   var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
   container.style.fontSize = (fontSize + (fontsize * 0.25)) + 'px';
}
```

Comment: Thanks\. I will use this if I can't find a way through CSS.

Answer (score 1):

125% of what?

It won't use the 15px, it is resetting the font-size for that element and will use (in this case) 125% of the default font-size which is (at least in my browser and in many if it hasn't been change) set at 16px.

Here in this snippet the first text explicitly has its font size set to 125% of 16px and the second is set by the buttons as in your code.

You will see that increase by 125% gives the same size.

```js
function increase() {
  //log("test");
  //var container = getElementById("container");
  container.classList.add("adjuster");
}

function decrease() {
  //var container = getElementById("container");
  container.classList.remove("adjuster");
}
```

```css
.standard {
  font-size: calc(125 * 16px / 100);
}

.main {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.adjuster {
  font-size: 125%;
}
```

```html
<div id="standard" class="standard">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div id="container" class="main">
  Lorem Ipsum
</div>

<button onclick="increase()">
Increase
</button>

<button onclick="decrease()">
Decrease
</button>
```

Comment: Right. The second class is overwriting the font size of the first class, not increasing it. If I was using EMs or REMs then a descendant element could have 1.25em and that would be 125% of the parent EM size. Since the parent element is set to PX that's the issue.

Comment: If the parent had a CSS variable size or user CSS property, then the descendant element could use calc(). But that seems like more work than using JS to manually.

Comment: I don't see why the parent element's being set to px value is an issue. 125% of the font-size is 125% of the font size whether that was set in px or ems or...

Answer (score 0):

You just must add `document` before get the html element
etc

```
document.getElementById("container");
```

You can learn deeply about html dom on https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

And you can make variable before the function (globar variable) so you can call that element without declare it every time

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
function increase() {
   //log("test");
   container.classList.add("adjuster");
}

function decrease() {
  container.classList.remove("adjuster");
}
```

```css
.main {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.adjuster {
  font-size: 125%; // increase by 25%
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="main">
   Lorem Ipsum
</div>

<button onclick="increase()">
Increase
</button>

<button onclick="decrease()">
Decrease
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for you comments. A few remarks to this. I was focusing on the example not as much the semantics. But FYI, I could have left the call out. If you give an element an ID you can simply reference the element by id without getting it through document.getElementById. Try it. Remove the `var container` line completely.